# How to make rest api end points in swagger UI pre authenticated in Spring BOOT

Tags: java, rest, spring, oauth2, swagger

I have written a spring boot rest API application with OAuth.I have integrated swagger UI for API documentation. I want the API endpoints on swagger UI to be accessible without an access token.

This is my swagger config :

```
    package com.XXX;
    
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
    import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
    import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
    import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
    import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2
    public class SwaggerConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public Docket blogApi() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("XXXXX"))
                    .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/v1.*"))
                    .build();
        }
    
    
    
    }
```

I tried adding these lines in my Resource server but still, the API's aren't accessible.

`http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").authenticated();`
and
`http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll();`